# Playing Audio During call so that other person on call can hear it

Tags: android

i am developing one application which
needs to play an audio song to callee when call is lifted by callee,
and automatically call has to be disconnected automatically when audio
song playing completed . i tried to find in android API for any
classes or methods to do this, but failed to find... please help me
how to do this..
your answer could be helpful to me...please do reply

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, it is *not* possible to play a sound in the ongoing call and also to automatically dosconnect a call. Telephont API doesnt provide any methods to do any od these. So both od these requirement can't be fullfilled in ANdroid.

Comment: if its helpful, accept so that others may know the chosen answer.

Comment: actually, ending calls is possible through reflection.